# How to assign assign condition using if statement and VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, if-statement, filter, excel-formula

I have the following data in an excel sheet named `players`

[image]

In a new sheet I have to filter the draft team name based on criteria of start match and end match

The data with the expected out should be highlighted as below:-

[image: Draft Team]

The criteria for Draft Team is based on column `Match` in the new data and columns `Start Match` and `'End Match'` from `players` sheet. For players `G` and `F` Draft Team is blank because `Match` is not within the `Start Match` and `End Match`.

How to get the highlighted expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use either `XLOOKUP()` or `INDEX()` with `MATCH()` Function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `L2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$10,
MATCH(1,(I2>=$F$2:$F$10)*(I2<=$G$2:$G$10)*(J2=$A$2:$A$10)*(K2=$B$2:$B$10),0)),"")
```

---

Or, with `XLOOKUP()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `L2`

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(I2>=$F$2:$F$10)*(I2<=$G$2:$G$10)*(J2=$A$2:$A$10)*(K2=$B$2:$B$10),$C$2:$C$10,"")
```

---

Comment: The formula is working. But I am getting the output as blank across all the cells.Will this work if I put different teams in column 'C'? In google sheets the output is '
   =IFERROR( VLOOKUP(E3, ArrayFormula(FILTER( 'Player Points - G5'!A:G,'Player Points - G5'!A:A = E3, 'Player Points - G5'!F:F <= A3, 'Player Points - G5'!G:G >= A3 )), 3, FALSE), "" )' . In excel it is '=IFERROR(__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION("IFERROR( VLOOKUP(E5, ArrayFormula(FILTER( 'Player Points - G5'!A:G,'Player Points - G5'!A:A = E5, 'Player Points - G5'!F:F <= A5, 'Player Points - G5'!G:G >= A5 )), 3, FALSE), """" )"),"EIC")'

Comment: @SriSreshtan you have tagged `Excel` and you are using google sheets right, both are different can you comment below the google sheet link?

Comment: I want to apply this in ' excel ' only. I mentioned the difference in how the formula is shown after downloading the google sheet as excel file.

Comment: And why are you downloading from google sheet, can you directly paste in excel. you need to change the range as per your suit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252775/discussion-between-sri-sreshtan-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).